# How to capture hot-key inputs when program is not focused?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java, which has to open up if you press a hot-key *(key combination. e.g: **Ctrl+L**)*, but the hot-keys work only if the GUI of my program is focused.

Is there a way for my program to capture hot-key presses, even when it is running on the background?

Comment: I guess that you want to configure that hotkey within your operating system to launch your app? Is that right?

Comment: Use some kind of "quick key" program to launch your program rather then trying to do this from within the program itself

Comment: not really, i want to start some function in my programm. As exable if i press Contol+P the programm will print something